# How to remove account in AccountManager in Android

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am trying to remove a custom account in AccountManager.

This is my code :

```
final Handler handler = new Handler (); 

AccountManagerCallback<Boolean> callback = new AccountManagerCallback<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> arg0)
            {
                String test = "test";
            }
        };

AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> bool = am.removeAccount(account, callback, handler);
```

Permissions I'm using :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

The account is never removed and the callback never called, any idea ? No trace in logs

Comment: Could you resolve this? I am facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 14):

Try this it will work

```
    // Global Variables 
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.example.package";
    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.example.package";
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "my_custom_account_name";

    // Account Manager definition
    AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) this.getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);

    // loop through all accounts to remove them
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
    for (int index = 0; index < accounts.length; index++) {
    if (accounts[index].type.intern() == AUTHORITY)
        accountManager.removeAccount(accounts[index], null, null);
    }
```

requires

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work.
You're basically doing the same thing as me.
The removeAccount() function doesn't do anything (and return nothing btw).

Comment: @user2083698 you might be doing something wrong its works perfect in my app

Comment: @user2083698 make sure you have above permission and your authority matches in if

Comment: Adding this permission does not change anything.
I posted all enabled permission on the first post.
And removing account from android's settings doesn't work neither.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show me a sample project which creates and removes an account ?

Comment: try Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
    for (int index = 0; index < accounts.length; index++) {}

Comment: Account is actually found but when I call the removeAccount() function on this account nothing happens.

Comment: You are wrong, doesn't need WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS for above code, instead of need 'GET_ACCOUNTS' and 'MANAGE_ACCOUNTS' permission. Plz correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn TableConstants.AUTHORITY ?? what is that String

Comment: @AZ_ its the unique identifier needed for content uri

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn Your code is working man. Only we have to allow removal in Authenticator class. +1

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn For adding or removing accounts, our app needs to hold  `android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS`. See [(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccount(android.accounts.Account, android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback<java.lang.Boolean>, android.os.Handler))]

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn -- I updated your code to make it clearer.  But thank you for posting it, it really helped me out (just needed some clarification which I added in the edit).

Answer (score 8):

You need to override the following method in the **Authenticator** class from **AbstractAccountAuthenticator**.

```
public Bundle getAccountRemovalAllowed(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response, Account account) {
    Bundle result = new Bundle();
    boolean allowed = true; // or whatever logic you want here
    result.putBoolean(AccountManager.KEY_BOOLEAN_RESULT, allowed);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to override the method in the `Authenticator` class from `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`? From what I understand from your answer, assuming Vico's code is in some method named `public void removing(){}`, one would first have to call the class `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` from somewhere, and then in that class in Vico's method `removing` one should paste your method `getAccountRemovalAllowed` with the text `@Override` above it. But I am having a bit diffuculty understanding how you could reach class `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` from Vico`s method `removing`.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            accountManager.removeAccount(account, {}, AContext.app.mainHandler)
        } else {
            accountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(account)
        }
```

For API 22 and higher works perfectly, but on API 19 didn't work at all.

Finally found the problem in my implementation of AbstractAccountAuthenticator:

```
override fun getAccountRemovalAllowed(response: AccountAuthenticatorResponse?, account: Account?): Bundle {
    AccountHelper.removeAccount()
    return super.getAccountRemovalAllowed(response, account)
}
```

It became to work after deleting "AccountHelper.removeAccount()"

I don't know - maybe it'll help

Answer (score 2):

You have to call 2 below methods before removeAccount method and the system will allow you to remove the account in account manager. 
clearPassword
invalidateAuthToken

Based on the description on the removeAccount method:

"The authenticator may have its own policies preventing account deletion, in which case the account will not be deleted."

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

This Code works like a charm to me.

You will need the WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS,also need to add android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS works for me with same code pattern. permission. So if you use AccountManager and Account correctly you will manage to remove the account successfully.

I had some issues using the account manager in the Android Simulator, so try to test on a real device...

```
AccountManager accMgr = AccountManager.get(this);
final Account account = new Account(username, accountType);

removeCaxtonAccount(accMgr, account);

public void removeCaxtonAccount(AccountManager accMgr, Account account){
        accMgr.removeAccount(account, null,null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. The previous solutions I found don't explicitly wait for the removal of accounts to finish so they randomly fail.

```
    final AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(getContext());
    final String accountType = AuthenticatorService.ACCOUNT_TYPE;

    final Account[] availableAccounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType);
    for (final Account availableAccount : availableAccounts) {
        final AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> booleanAccountManagerFuture = accountManager.removeAccount(availableAccount, null, null);
        assertTrue("Impossible to delete existing account for this application", booleanAccountManagerFuture.getResult(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }
```

Note: You still need the permissions mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

I my case for api before 22 adding `Authenticator` class helped. Just inspire yourself from this source https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=MLNO/airgram/airgram-master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/ir/hamzad/telegram/ContactsController.java#

for api 22+ this works without `Authenticator`:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
    Timber.e(String.valueOf(accountManager.removeAccountExplicitly(account)));
}`